# Who invented finding volumes through revolution?

Tags: calculus, math-history, volume, solid-of-revolution

If this can't be found, which famous mathematician(s) worked on further developing the idea of finding volumes through revolution?

Comment: [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes#Mathematics) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean [Pappus of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus_of_Alexandria). See

- [Pappus's centroid theorem at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)
- [Pappus's Centroid Theorem at Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PappussCentroidTheorem.html)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!